# How to compare DB results with Excel file data in Java?

Tags: java, sql, excel, oracle

I am trying to write some tests that would compare and assert that db data are the same with my exit data (some excel file).
I am querying oracle table with some `SELECT` and got `ResultSet`. Or I can get it to `List<String>`.
But I have no idea how to compare each row's data (with multiple columns) with predefined data that I would store in a file. It would probably excel file, but I guess I can convert it to any other file type, if only it could make the comparison easier.

EDIT:
What I've done so far (based on comment from g00se and also on other posts from stackoverflow)

```
    public static List<User> convertExcelFileToObject(String filePath) {
    ArrayList<User> UsersList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        for(int i=sheet.getFirstRowNum()+1;i<=sheet.getLastRowNum();i++){
            User User= new User();
            Row row=sheet.getRow(i);
            for(int j=row.getFirstCellNum();j<=row.getLastCellNum();j++){
                Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
                if(j==0){
                    User.setUserId(cell.getStringCellValue());
                }
                if(j==1){
                    User.setUserName(cell.getStringCellValue());
                }
                if(j==2){
                    User.setSurnameName(cell.getStringCellValue());
                }
            }
            UsersList.add(User);
        }
        file.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return UsersList;
}
```

and

```
    public static List<User> convertDbResultsToObject(String sqlQuery) throws SQLException {
    ResultSet resultSet = DatabaseManager.getData(sqlQuery);

    List<User> Users=new ArrayList<User>();
    while(resultSet.next()) {
        User User = new User();
        User.setUserId(resultSet.getString("USER_ID"));
        User.setUserName(resultSet.getString("USER_NAME"));
        User.setSurnameName(resultSet.getString("SURNAME_NAME"));
        Users.add(User);
    }
    return Users;
}
```

having those two Lists of Users, I am comparing them with some assertEquals.

Comment: As well as being architecturally sounder, it would probably be easier to compare two objects (or collection thereof), the one created from the db, the other from the spreadsheet

Comment: I think I know how to convert the excel file to object, but how to convert DB data to one?

Comment: If your table has a *primary key* (as it should) and the excel file a corresponding unique key, you may want to identify the keys that are in one source only (first difference). For keys in both sources you may show the not equal attributes (second difference). If you can load the excel in the DB, you may do this using *SQL* (full outer join + attribute comparison). For a *large data* you'll be probaly more *preformant* that a DIY *Java comparison*.

Comment: *I think I know how to convert the excel file to object, but how to convert DB data to one?* I suspect you might not, as the two would be pretty similar. What table are you selecting and what are its principal columns?

Comment: let me edit the main post, and I would be grateful for your feedback if that's right approach. It works, but I don't know if this is a good approach

Comment: A totally different approach would be to expose the file as an external table in oracle. Then you can write a single query against both file and table to determine the differences instead of inventing the wheel yourself like you're doing now.

Comment: The code you have posted in your question is a good approach, but you should post it as an *answer* instead.